# How to make a simple countdown in Vue3?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I've been trying to set-up a simple countdown using Vue3, but I cant make it to work properly. This would be so easy to make in React, but I simply dont understand the logic in Vue (3). So, I've come up with this:

```js
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            timer: 10,
            interval: ""
        }
    },
    emits: ["start-game"],
    methods: {
        startGame() {
            this.$emit("start-game")

            this.startTimer()
        },
        startTimer() {
            clearInterval(this.interval)

            while(this.timer != 0) {
                this.interval = setInterval(() => {
                    this.timer--
                }, 1000)
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

You would expect this to work but it creates an infinite loop. Somehow, you cant just use `while` inside of vue methods. If I remove the `while` it actually counts down indefinitely, but I need other functions to run once the timer runs out (hits 0). What is the Vue way to handle such things?

Comment: You might find this helpful https://github.com/mabarbeau/countdown-timer/blob/master/src/views/Timer.vue

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't think this has anything to do with React or Vue. You need to clear your interval in the `setInterval` callback so that it knows when to stop. No need for the `while` loop:

```js
this.interval = setInterval(() => {
  if (this.timer === 0) {
    clearInterval(this.interval)                
  } else {
    this.timer--
  }             
}, 1000)
```

Also checkout this pure js example:

```js
let timer = 10;
let interval = setInterval(() => {
  if (timer === 0) {
    clearInterval(interval)                
  } else {
    timer--
    console.log(timer)
  }             
}, 1000)
```

Comment: should write the code inside the onMounted?

Answer (score 1):

I got the same trouble, I was super happy in react to have `react-hook-timer` but nothing in vue 3 .
So i made it you have 3 main features:

- timer
- stopwatch
- time

For your use case, timer is the one you need, follow these steps:

`npm i vue-timer-hook`

```js
<script setup>
  import { useTimer } from "vue-timer-hook";

  const timer = useTimer(10 * 1000, false);
  const startGame = () {
    timer.start()
  }
  watchEffect(() => {
    if(timer.isExpired.value) {
        console.warn('IsExpired')
    }
  })
</script>
```

https://github.com/riderx/vue-timer-hook

Answer (score 0):

To get this to work I did this in `mount()`:

```js
let this_ = this;  // to make this available as a closure
setInterval(() => {
    this_.$options.timer.bind(this_)();  // methods are available in $options, need to bind `this`
}, 1000)
```